# Height issues in website

Tags: html, css

I am creating a site for which I have created a structure but I am facing height issue in that. here is what I am expecting

[image: Expecting]

but this is what I am getting

[image: Final]
Below is the CSS:

```
html {height:100%!important;}
body {
    margin:0;
    font:12px/15px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    color:#8a8a8a;
    min-width:1000px;
    background:#fff;
    min-height:100%!important;
}

#wrapper {
    position:relative;
    min-height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:url(../images/wrapper.jpeg) repeat-y;
}
#content {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Do you actually want the text to occupy the whole area? If so just use `height:100%;`

Comment: I want to have a full length left and right section

Comment: This example I did with some of your code should help you a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/fA4HL/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100% is just getting set to 100% of the content in it , try using a pixel height instead

```
#content {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    min-height:500px;
}
```

Comment: But the container can grow upon the user selection of data.. will it grow to the length to what user demand. Just like facebook

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite - min-height means at least 500px tall , if content is more then 500px it will expand

Answer (score 0):

I would put a `min-height` in pixels on your wrapper. Since the #content is set to 100% height, it will fill all of the wrapper.

This way, if there is less content than needed to fill the full height of the browser, the page will add whitespace below your content to fill the browser height. I do this often when first building out a new page, since I don't have any content, but want to get an idea of how it will look when filling the browser window.

I would suggest doing something like this:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../images/wrapper.jpeg) repeat-y;
}
```

You might want to adjust the `min-height` in pixels to fit your site- whatever it takes to make it fill the browser window.